# What is the technique that the 'top' program uses to redisplay data on the screen?

Tags: c++, c, linux, terminal, command-line-interface

As you probably know, when you run the "top" command in a terminal, it will show you the busiest processes on your computer and update the values periodically without adding a single line.

What is the technique called that allows it do this — to change the printed string from a CLI program?

Comment: If you don't want to use `curses`, you can almost always use ANSI escape codes (`"\033[H\033[2J"` to clear the terminal screen and move the cursor to the origin). At worst, if the terminal does not support it, you get seven garbage bytes on it. Practically all current terminals support at least the basic ANSI escapes. In Linux, `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` returns 1 if standard input is a terminal; if it is, then normal ANSI escape sequences almost certainly work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to get the get the width/height of the terminal window, and just clear/print whole screen every time. Another way is to use [VT100 escape codes](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes) to reposition cursor and overwrite whats on that position. A third way is to use a library such as [`ncurses`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: Note, that the third way is a subset of the second way :)

Answer (score 2):

Terminal accepts some control sequences for screen positioning, etc. Look into `curses`/[`ncurses`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) library. Also, if you want to modify just one line you can do with just using `\r` and printing over that line again.